# How to data-bind .resizable().draggable()?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I know you can do this:

```
$(".myClass").resizable().draggable();
```

but how would you use `data-bind=""` to do the same thing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The simplest way would be to define custom binding handlers for the behaviors:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.resizable = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
         var options = valueAccessor();
         $(element).resizable(options);
    }  
};

ko.bindingHandlers.draggable = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
         var options = valueAccessor();
         $(element).draggable(options);
    }  
};
```

Then, bind to it like:

```
<div data-bind="resizable: { }, draggable: { }"></div>
```

This allows you to pass any options that you want to the resizable and draggable calls.

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/eCZH4/

Comment: Hi i am new to js ! could you please tell me what is ko? i am getting  error like 'ko is not defined'. Thanks